# When importing multiple CSV files, filter rows to be imported by top cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to import large number of CSV files that include data for multiple days.

Here is an example data, first five rows:

```
PostDaily;07.04.2019
Leg Number;Aircraft Manufacturer;Aircraft Type;Day Of Origin;AC Logical Number;Airline Designator;Flight Number;Flight Number Suffix;Tail Sign;Scheduled Departure Airport;Scheduled Arrival Airport;Scheduled Departure DateTime;Scheduled Arrival DateTime;Offset DA;Offset AA;Actual Departure Airport;Actual Arrival Airport;Actual Departure DateTime;Actual Arrival DateTime;Flight Type;Pax Booked;Pax Flown;Crew;Leg State;Meals;Best;Biz
27507094;Other;73H;06.04.2019;29;WW;0584; ;-GABAF-;GGN;PMI;06.04.2019 02:35;06.04.2019 05:00;+02:00;+02:00;CGN;PMI;06.04.2019 02:40;06.04.2019 04:52;J;129;123;X3.../X3...//X3TUI;ARR;41;0;0
27507179;Other;73H;06.04.2019;29;WW;0585; ;-GABAF-;PMI;GGN;06.04.2019 05:45;06.04.2019 08:05;+02:00;+02:00;PMI;CGN;06.04.2019 05:44;06.04.2019 07:48;J;41;40;X3.../X3...//X3TUI;ARR;29;0;0
27506541;Other;73H;06.04.2019;29;WW;0526; ;-GABAF-;GGN;BCN;06.04.2019 09:30;06.04.2019 11:50;+02:00;+02:00;CGN;BCN;06.04.2019 09:44;06.04.2019 11:47;J;183;174;X3.../X3...//X3TUI;ARR;50;0;0
```

Unfortunately, the data overlaps and I need to modify my existing import code so that python only imports the rows that have the same value in the column "Date of Origin" as the top row (which also needs to be deleted at the end). Moreover, the import script needs to work on Mac and Windows.

This is the code I use to import the CSV files. It works very well until I realised that there are duplicates (not 100% duplicates as some rows have different values) in the CSV files.

```
sector_ytd = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, delimiter=";", skiprows=1) for f in sector_folder.glob('4UDailyPos*.csv')], ignore_index = True)
```

The first row in each CSV file contains this data:

```
PostDaily;07.04.2019
```

Now I would like to only import or concat the rows of my CSV file where the column `Date of Origin` equals the date in the first row (after `PostDaily`;)

The outcome would be that I have one dataframe with date rows of several days, but no more duplicates.

Comment: Are the dates `mm.dd.yyyy` or `dd.mm.yyyy` format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not create a function to parse each file? Below is a way to get the date from the top of the file and then filter the DataFrame to only return the lines that match the date.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

def parse_file(file):

    # Grab the first line of the file
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        first_line = f.readline()

    # Parse the date out from the first line
    day = first_line.split(';')[1].strip()

    # Go ahead and read in the entire csv file
    df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=';', header=1)

    # Return the data from just that one day
    return df.loc[df['Day Of Origin'] == day]


df = parse_file('log.csv')
print(df[['Leg Number', 'Aircraft Type', 'Day Of Origin']])

#    Leg Number Aircraft Type Day Of Origin
# 1    27507179           73H    07.04.2019
# 2    27506541           73H    07.04.2019
# 3    27507179           73H    07.04.2019
# 4    27506541           73H    07.04.2019
```

Then to loop through them all, just use your `concat` method

```
sector_ytd = pd.concat(
    # Pass your filename to the function rather going straight to pd.read_csv()
    [parse_file(f) for f in sector_folder.glob('4UDailyPos*.csv')],
    ignore_index = True)
```

To show you that the function filters, here's the csv file I used. It's a bit modified form what you posted so that it contained valid and invalid rows.

```
PostDaily;07.04.2019
Leg Number;Aircraft Manufacturer;Aircraft Type;Day Of Origin;AC Logical Number;Airline Designator;Flight Number;Flight Number Suffix;Tail Sign;Scheduled Departure Airport;Scheduled Arrival Airport;Scheduled Departure DateTime;Scheduled Arrival DateTime;Offset DA;Offset AA;Actual Departure Airport;Actual Arrival Airport;Actual Departure DateTime;Actual Arrival DateTime;Flight Type;Pax Booked;Pax Flown;Crew;Leg State;Meals;Best;Biz
27507094;Other;73H;06.04.2019;29;EW;0584; ;-GABAF-;GGN;PMI;06.04.2019 02:35;06.04.2019 05:00;+02:00;+02:00;CGN;PMI;06.04.2019 02:40;06.04.2019 04:52;J;129;123;X3.../X3...//X3TUI;ARR;41;0;0
27507179;Other;73H;07.04.2019;29;EW;0585; ;-GABAF-;PMI;GGN;06.04.2019 05:45;06.04.2019 08:05;+02:00;+02:00;PMI;CGN;06.04.2019 05:44;06.04.2019 07:48;J;41;40;X3.../X3...//X3TUI;ARR;29;0;0
27506541;Other;73H;07.04.2019;29;EW;0526; ;-GABAF-;GGN;BCN;06.04.2019 09:30;06.04.2019 11:50;+02:00;+02:00;CGN;BCN;06.04.2019 09:44;06.04.2019 11:47;J;183;174;X3.../X3...//X3TUI;ARR;50;0;0
27507179;Other;73H;07.04.2019;29;EW;0585; ;-GABAF-;PMI;GGN;06.04.2019 05:45;06.04.2019 08:05;+02:00;+02:00;PMI;CGN;06.04.2019 05:44;06.04.2019 07:48;J;41;40;X3.../X3...//X3TUI;ARR;29;0;0
27506541;Other;73H;07.04.2019;29;EW;0526; ;-GABAF-;GGN;BCN;06.04.2019 09:30;06.04.2019 11:50;+02:00;+02:00;CGN;BCN;06.04.2019 09:44;06.04.2019 11:47;J;183;174;X3.../X3...//X3TUI;ARR;50;0;0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. With this method I would have to specify the name of each file I import, correct? I am trying to avoid this as I am importing lots of files and I am currently saving them all in one folder "sector_folder"

Comment: You would have to send each file to the function just like you were sending it to `pd.read_csv()` in your list comprehension. So you would just need to modify the list comprehension a bit as i showed. Granted, you'll still have a bit of tweaking to do in your function since I don't really know  your data structure in the files, but this should help get you there.

Comment: Sorry, but I am confused as I have never worked with parsing. Is there any way I could make it work with my existing code by just tweaking this one a bit.

Comment: When I use your code I get "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Can you paste the first few lines of an output file in your question? I assume the line you're getting that error on is the `day = first_line.split(',')[1]` You probably need to change the comma to a semicolon. I just created a mock csv file so i could test my function. I included the contents of my csv so you could see the differences in what i used and what you have in your actual files to make the necessary tweaks.

Comment: I just added it in the question

Comment: Update the answer. Copy the function and the modification to the list comprehension and it should work just fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191917/discussion-between-brian-cohan-and-manuh).